# inserting a node at the end of a linked list in c++

Tags: c++, linked-list

For the node :

```
struct node
{ int data;
  struct node *next;
};

node *tmp = new node;
tmp->data=1;
tmp->next = nullptr;
```

To add this we use:

```
tail->next=tmp;
tail=tail->next;
```

Why don't we write:

```
tail->next=tmp;
tail=tmp;
```

Comment: You can if you want to. The end result is the same either way.

Comment: Either is acceptable, but one could argue that in the second case you have to change `tmp` in two places, not one, if you change the variable name. The performance issue is not worth bothering about.

Comment: If you eliminate `tmp` by writing `tail->next = new node(1)`, you don't have a choice.

Answer (score 1):

While the ultimate result is the same, the first expresses the intent – update `tail` to point to the newly-inserted last node – clearer.

The correctness of the second is much less obvious, and requires some thinking (and the context of the line before it) to figure out why anyone would point `tail` to a temporary node.